# How to check child node exist or not using CQ 5 Query builder

Tags: aem, query-builder, xpathquery

using query builder i want to check whether a node exist or not ? Is there any way to achieve this.

Here is the parameter i'm using

```
path=/etc/commerce/products/abc
type=nt:unstructured
property=cq:commerceType
property.value=product
nodename=images
node.operations=not
p.limit=-1
```

But it's not working. Operation =not is not valid parameter for node type. Is there any other way ?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use query builder to find this out?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. Regardless, if you have a seeming valid query that returns no results, you should be safe to assume the node doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Query Builder to check for a node's existence, simply take advantage of Apache Sling's RESTful API by making a GET request to the node. You will receive the proper HTTP status code in response, either `200` or `404`.

```
$.get('/etc/commerce/products/abc.json')
  .done(function(){
    console.log('node exists');
  })
  .fail(function(){
    console.log('node does not exist');
  });
```